# progressbar disappears before the image appears

Tags: java, android, progress-bar, android-glide

I have an application receives  data (**images**) from json, I'm trying to show a `Progressbar` while image is loaded, but `Progressbar` gone before image appears, I want to make progressbar appears while image is loaded I'm using **Glide library**.

can I make the progress bar visible always behind the image view?

My **adapter.java**:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private List<Post> posts;
    private Context context;
    private RecyclerViewClickListener mClickListener;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    public MyAdapter(List<Post> posts, Context context, RecyclerViewClickListener clickListener) {
        this.posts = posts;
        this.context = context;
        this.mClickListener = clickListener;
    }
    public List<Post> getItems(){
        return posts;
    }
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.picture_item,
                parent, false);

        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.bindModel(posts.get(position));
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() { return posts.size(); }
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        Post mPost;
        ImageView image;
        ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cat_imageView);
            progressBar = (ProgressBar) itemView.findViewById(R.id.progress);
            progressBar.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
            v.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
        void bindModel(Post post) {
            this.mPost = post;
            Glide
                    .with(context)
                    .load(post.getImgUrl())
                    .asBitmap()
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                    .priority(Priority.HIGH)
                    .listener(new RequestListener<String, Bitmap>() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<Bitmap> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                            return false;
                        }
                        @Override
                        public boolean onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, String model, Target<Bitmap> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            return false;
                        }
                    }).into(image);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mClickListener.onClick(view, mPost);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this may help you,

**EDIT**

Use **`Glide v-4.2.0`** update **`gradle.build()`**

```
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.2.0'
```

Then use below code this is working for me

```
  Glide.with(context)
            .load((post.getImgUrl()))
            .apply(new RequestOptions()
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
            .priority(Priority.HIGH))
            .listener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {


        @Override
        public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            return false;
        }
    }).into(image);
```

see the image below

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer but  i can't find `public boolean onLoadFailed ...` i can use only the `onException` and `onResourceReady`

Comment: Yeah I am sorry for that I think you are using Glide 3.3.0

Comment: can i make progress bar visible always behind imageview ?

Comment: i get this error : 
`listener
(com.bumptech.glide.request.RequestListener<? super java.lang.String,android.graphics.Bitmap>)
in BitmapRequestBuilder cannot be applied
to
(anonymous com.bumptech.glide.request.RequestListener<java.lang.String,com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.drawable.GlideDrawable>)`

Comment: Let me check i am implementing Glide to my side actually i was worked with old version Please give my some time i trying to solve your problem

Comment: Can you tell me Which glide version you are using

Comment: @safae see the edited answer. Working perfectly at my side and sorry for being late actually my system is too slow :(

Comment: thanks so much actually i'm using glide v3.8.0 but i will try to update it

Answer (score 0):

```
.listener(new RequestListener<String, Bitmap>() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<Bitmap> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                            **progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);**
                            return false;
                        }
                        @Override
                        public boolean onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, String model, Target<Bitmap> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            **image.setImageBitmap(resource);**
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
```

Instead of using Glide method into()...try to use bitmap which you get in onResourceReady() and set into imageview. It worked for me.